# Proving RC and RL circuits as integrator and differentiator using differential equations

Tags: capacitor, inductor, theory

I need to use **first degree ordinary differantial equations** to prove (solve) the **Differentiator** and **Integrator** Circuits of **RL** and **RC** (for example if RL is differeantiator or integaror or both i need to prove it with using first order ordinary differeantial equations).

Btw I know how to use differential equations but i dont know how to use them on circuits so i would be happy if you also show me the solution of some to solve others or maybe hint,tip etc. or some sources where i can learn this about and sorry for my english and this is my first question on this site. Waiting for your answers. :)

Comment: Perhaps you could ask what you don't understand about Mr. Wiki's fine math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_circuit

Comment: A simple RC (or RL) is neither a perfect integrator nor a perfect differentiator because of the presence of the resistor. (Hint: don't waste your time trying to prove it).

Comment: @Andyaka Well since it'll affect my grades i'll have to. So please dont type things that dont helps me :).

Comment: @glen_geek wikipedia doesnt solve it with dif. eq. its just shows it.

Comment: Banishing the truth is a dangerous thing to do. Your question is flawed if you are trying to prove something that doesn't exist for the rest of us (or maybe your translation of the problem is flawed). You need to think about this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like a homework problem with no attempt to solve. Electrical Engineers should be able to attempt to solve problems

Comment: @Andyaka Don't get me wrong i completely agree with you. But if i just go to my teacher and say "Hey this can't be a perfect integrator nor a perfect differentiator because of the presence of the resistor". I dont think he will care. He doesnt even gave us a circuit to solve he just said find if rl rc has integrator or differentiator(which both rl rc has) then prove them with dif. eq.

Comment: @laptop2d how do you know there is no attempt ? Just because i did done attempt but yesterday i realised that on my calculations i took some variables as a constant and thanks to a guy who gave me completely wrong equations(which was also my fault to directly use that eq.) which made me return where i start.

Comment: @laptop2d And ironicaly i am a computer engineer who plans to work on completely software related jobs. But thanks to "Education System" i stuck here :). So i would be glad if you just start voting all of a sudden.

Comment: Please read the [help] for what is considered on-topic here. We are not a general EE forum and we don't provide solutions to homework problem for free. The goal of this site is to create an high quality knowledge base in Q&A form. As a person requesting help you are required to fulfill some basic criteria, if you want us to help. Whatever effort you have put in solving your problem, sorry to be blunt, we don't care. You must **show** us your efforts. Saying you did is not enough. As it stands, your question doesn't show any attempt whatsoever.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Well, if you'd just scrolled down and fully inspect the topic you would see that i shared my progress. Tomorrow is the last day and i already finished 90% of my homework thanks to other guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Photon has shown the basic math relating current to voltage. Look at the differentiator (engineers can't help referring to circuits). At left, the driving function is represented by a Voltage source (Vin), which varies with time:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0mKqC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Current is produced by Vin that is common to C1 and to R1. As shown by The Photon, current is proportional to the derivative of Vin. But for this to be true, *all of Vin must appear across C1*. That leaves no voltage at Vout (voltage across R1 will be zero).
So we compromise a little, and we say that Vout is *almost* differentiating Vin, so long as Vout is *very small*. It is an approximation. If Vin has a rate-of-change that is too high, Vout becomes too large, and the approximation fails.
**An example Vin:**
Let us say that Vin is a ramp whose voltage rises with time...Vin=+10volts/sec. And let us make the assumption that all this voltage appears across C1.
Then I = C * 10, I=10uA
This current will produce a voltage across R of 10uA * 100 ohms = +0.001v.
Now if Vin starts at zero volts and rises from there, for awhile it is not larger than 0.001v, so Vout cannot be said to represent a proper differentiated voltage. But later, when Vout rises to a larger voltage (above approximately 0.1v), the approximation becomes more true, and Vout rises toward 0.001v. After awhile, Vin becomes much larger than Vout, and Vout approaches very close to +0.001v.
And if Vin *changes too quickly*, then Vout will be larger, making the approximation untrue. These circuits only approach their mathematical ideal only when Vout << Vin.

You have an integrator (at right), with Vout representing voltage across the capacitor. Here, R2 must see nearly all of Vin, so that current is equal to Vin/R2. In this case too, Vout << Vin is the required condition for the integration to be true. In this case, Vin must be very much larger than Vout, and/or it must change very quickly.
 This integrator fails to integrate a steady voltage at Vin because Vout eventually rises to equal that steady voltage (violating the approximation that Vout << Vin). It really only integrates rapid changes of Vin, so that those changes of Vout are much less than changes of Vin.

---

**Example Vin for the case of Resistor-Inductor**
Again, Vin starts at zero and rises linearly at a rate of 10v/sec. For the resistor-inductor differentiator, Vout is taken across the inductor L1(0.01 henries) in the circuit below. And once again, Vout must be very much smaller than Vin. Thus, almost all of Vin appears across R3, so that *I* = Vin/R3. Now *I* is rising *0.1A/sec*. When this current is applied to inductor L1, a *constant voltage* is produced...(V = L * di/dt). That voltage is L * *I* = .01 * *.1* = .001 volts.
Notice that this resistor-inductor differentiator yields the same Vout as the resistor-capacitor differentiator above. The time constant of the two circuits are identical...RC = L/R.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqtICw.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for spending time your explanation really helped. I am not good at english but i think i started to understand the point and I'll just try to analyze it more . Btw would it be correct if i just take those integrator and differentiator circuits and apply them kirchoff then combine the answer with dif. eq.  on previous comments? And about RL circuits is it just replacing capacitors with inductor or does it have different schematic?

Comment: Series RL circuit can differentiate Vin if you take Vout across L, and can integrate if you take Vout across R. As always, Vout << Vin approximation is required.

Comment: Thanks again. Looking the schematics on the internet now. Btw i choosed your reply as solution because it covers everything i wondered. I'll try to solve them now.

Comment: @onurcevik, whoops, missed my numbers by orders of magnitude, have corrected my answer. (C1 = 1x10^-6)

Comment: Thanks for your answers and sorry for late answer.your answer helpmed me the understand it and i used the formulas that The Photon gaved me  and kirchoff laws and so far i solved RC as both differentiator and integrator assuming R and C so large for integrator and so low for differentiator. But i stuck with RL i used kirchoff and get equation : Vi=Ldi/dt + Rdq/dt and if i see R as small it gaves me eq: Vi=L(di/dt) and if i integrate it it becomes : 1/L (integral) vi = i which is the point im stuck now. Any idea ?

Comment: @onurcevik added the case of resistor-inductor differentiator. Again, the rule is that Vout<<Vin, so that circuit current becomes Vin/R. For the resistor-inductor integrator, almost all of Vin appears across L2...and creates the dominant current to feed R4.

Answer (score 2):

Just as linear resistors are defined by Ohm's Law, there are defining equations for linear capacitors and inductors. For a capacitor

$$Q = CV$$

or, in terms of a derivative

$$I = C\frac{\rm{d}V}{\rm{d}t}$$

For an inductor

$$\frac{\rm{d}I}{\rm{d}t}=\frac{V}{L}$$.

Combine these with Kirchoff's Laws and you will have differential equations describing your circuit.

Comment: +1 for showing that only a pure L or C can integrate or differentiate.

Comment: Yeah but how do i solve them to prove RC(for example) as integrator or differentiator? I mean i already started to solve it but i really dont know how to finish it. Our instructor really didnt teached us about it too much all we did was just watching youtube videos on class and he gave us 1 week for this.

Comment: @onur, your question says "I know how to use differential equations"... so go ahead from here. Like  Andy says, it will only be approximately an integrator or differentiator, not a perfect one. For example, in the RC "integrator" you'll need to consider cases where \$v_o \ll v_i\$.

Comment: @ThePhoton The problem is i dont know how to use them on circuits. Thats what my teacher wants so even if will be approximately i have to solve it. So any help is greatly appreciated. And about kirchoffs laws https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws

Comment: which formula on that link ill use to combine with yours ?

Comment: @onurcevik It depends on what your circuit looks like, you have a schematic, right?

Comment: @Tyler no i dont have any schematic. It just says prove RL and RC circuit blah blah ... But i'll use the simple circuits. The point is here proving RL and RC as both integrator and differentiator.

Comment: @onur, RE: "The problem is i dont know how to use them on circuits"; This is what my answer is trying to explain. You have a differential equation for each inductor or capacitor in the circuit. Kirchoff's Laws tell you how to combine them, depending on the connections in your circuit. I can hardly give you more without just doing your homework for you.

Comment: @ThePhoton Well I'm not native speaker so i think i couldnt deliver my problem I've got 1 week to do this homework without even proper education thanks to our instructor. I'm not trying to make you do my homework please dont get me wrong. Since i have been doing research for days. But thanks for helping. My last question was Which kirchoff law should i use to combine with your formulas. And how do solve the same equation as both integrator and differentiator.

Comment: @Onur, you can use either Kirchoff law. If you use KCL, it's called nodal analysis. If you use KVL it's called mesh analysis. In principle, mesh analysis is easier to use if your power sources are voltage sources and KCL is easier to use if your power sources are current sources. But there are fix-ups to allow you to use either one for any circuit.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and sorry for late answer. I used your formulas and kirchoff laws and so far i solved RC as both differentiator and integrator assuming R and C so large for integrator and so low for differentiator. But i stuck with RL i used kirchoff and get equation : Vi=Ldi/dt + Rdq/dt and if i see R as small it gaves me eq: Vi=L(di/dt) and if i integrate it it becomes : 1/L (integral) vi = i which is the point im stuck now. Any idea ?

Comment: @onurcevik, 1. \$\rm{d}q/\rm{d}t\=i$, no reason to write that part as a derivative. 2. In the RC case, you considered the case where *v* is small; so by duality in the RL case you should consider the case where *i* is small, not R, though it should lead you to the same result. 3. If you got to \$i = 1/2 \int v_i \rm{d}t\$, you've shown that the circuit is an integrator---isn't that what you were trying to prove?

Comment: Note that in the RL case, the voltage across the resistor will be proportional to the current (even if it's small), in case you feel you need the output variable to be a voltage.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am totally confused right now :/ 1) I didnt get which  equation are you talking about on your first sentence (syntax). 2) http://imgur.com/a/l3rOC When i solved RC as integrator i showed answer related to output voltage (Vo= 1/RC∫Vi). I didnt get how you find 1/2∫vidt . And shouldnt i find the answer related to Vo like i did in RC why are we assuming i as small on this one and in my eq. if i assume i as small it eliminates the same term (Rdq/dt) .Sorry for asking too much question :( . But  i got 1 day left to give my homework to professor.